# Changing aegis's astral suit mid-day

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, aegis

I need to confirm that I understand how the aegis's astral suit works.

My understanding is, I'm a 1st-level Aegis, and in the morning I form an astral skin, and I choose nimble (dex+2) and speed twice (+10ft). Now for the reast of the day, these are what I have, and I can't change. Next morning I form astral armor with etc...

No other way to change or alternate the suit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s incorrect.

> An astral suit can be dismissed as a free action.

> #### Astral Skin
>
> [...] Forming an astral suit into this form takes a swift action.

> #### Astral Armor
>
> [...] Forming an astral suit into this form takes a move action.

> #### Astral Juggernaut
>
> [...] Forming an astral suit into this form takes a full-round action.

There is no daily limit on how often you can form an astral suit, so you can dismiss your current choices as a free action, and then form the suit anew as a swift, move, or full-round action. You can do that as often as you like.

Note that you cannot change your customizations as easily—normally, changing those requires 8 hours of work. But the reconfigure ability gained at 3rd level allows some limited changes to be made to your customizations without spending 8 hours.